# Increment a character's ascii code

Tags: python, tkinter, ascii

In the code below, where I am learning Tkinter, I would like it so that a button press or key press changes the text from "A" to "B".  As you can see, it starts at "A" ... and then cheats by explicitly changing it to "B".  I want to access the first position in the StringVar (probably index 0), and then increment it as a character based on its ascii code, then convert it back to the StringVar.  Is this possible?  Is there a simpler way than using StringVar here?

[image][image]

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
print "this is a test"


class Demo(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.createGUI()
        print "init"
        #self.__mainWindow = Tk()
    def destroy(self):
        print "destroy"
    def createGUI(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
        self.master.title("Demo")
        self.trackLabel = StringVar()
        self.trackLabel.set("A")
        self.trackDisplay = Label(self, font = "Courier 14", textvariable = self.trackLabel, bg = "black", fg = "green")
        self.trackDisplay.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S)
        self.button1 = Button(self, text = "Move Forward", width = 20, command = self.bpress)
        self.button1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W+E+N+S)
        self.bind_all('<Key>', self.print_contents)


    def bpress(self):
        self.trackLabel.set("B") # I want to do this so it cycles through the alphabet!
        print "ow"
        #INSTEAD I WANT TO MAKE TRACKLABEL ASCII CHAR + 1 HERE
    def print_contents(self, event):
        print "testing here...", self.trackLabel.get()
        #INSTEAD I WANT THIS TO MAKE TRACKLABEL ASCII CHAR + 1 HERE BY KEY, OR ABOVE BY BUTTON PRESS
# run the program
def main():
    tts = Demo()
    tts.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a character's ascii code using `ord` and convert a code back into a character using `chr`.

```
code = ord(self.trackLabel.get())
self.trackLabel.set(chr(code+1))
```